# Why does this loop in Java cause a stack overflow error?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm learning Java using edX and I've seen this question about a nested loop.

[image: stack overflow error]

I thought it was the second option below but I've learned that it will actually result in a Stack overflow error. Could someone explain what that is and why it would cause that?

Comment: It doesn't. Second answer is correct. Try it for yourself!

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post code as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: I don't see how this would burn through the stack. You'd need to do many nested function calls for that.

Comment: None of those options is correct. It goes haywire printing stars in the inner loop because you're incrementing `i` instead of `j`; and the outer loop becomes infinite because the inner loop overflows `i`; but it doesn't stack overflow.

Comment: It seams as the site you use to learn messed their answers up. This code is not a good example for the problem of a stack overflow error, since it will not create one. It is more likly to create an OutOfMemoryException, but even this probably not. `void Foo() { Foo(); }` - if this method is called it will create an Stack overflow error as it will put more and more stackframes on the stack until the stack is full.

Comment: Please paste the code into the question as text. As it, it is unreadable (by me).

Answer (score 0):

It is why because i is taking 0 to 4 seemingly but gets incremented in the for loop condition of j which makes j loop unable to pop out as j is not getting incremented to dissatisfy the condition j<i and thus j is always gonna be less than i resulting in an overflow error

Comment: But not a stack overflow.

Comment: Yes , that’s why I just mentioned overflow

Answer (score 0):

you are not incrementing j and therefore j will always smaller than i causing infinite loop

Comment: But not a stack overflow.

Comment: i think the question is about memory space and and hence infinite loop will result in stack overflow

Comment: Infinite loops do not result in SOEs. Infinite *recursion* does.